# Install Errors for SQL Server 2005 and 2008 on Vista x64

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, windows-vista

I'm having very strange issues installing either SQL 2008 or 2005 on my local dev machine running Vista Business 64 SP1. It gets to the end of the installation process, then complains about not being able to connect to an RPC server. It immediately pop ups a vista error that the system is shutting down because of a critical error.

When the system comes back up, the same shut down notice appears and shuts down again. I have to boot into safe mode and turn off the SQL server services.

I've tried turning off Windows Firewall and Windows Defender thinking that there may have been a conflict, but the same error occurs without fail.

The event viewer tells me that lsass.exe failed with status code 255 and that it faulted in ncrypt.dll.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

No, but I think installing SP2 on that Vista machine would be a really wise thing to do.